# THROW after Rollbacking transaction SQL

Tags: sql-server-2014

Hi all I have a stored procedure where I have gone for Transaction as per the requirement, this is my SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName
@Id INT,
@user_id INT
AS
 BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [transName]
    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE 
        FROM    table1
        WHERE   UserId= @user_id 

        UPDATE  table2
        SET     DATE_MODIFIED = GETDATE()
        WHERE   ID= @Id

        COMMIT TRANSACTION [transName]

    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [transName]
        THROW
END CATCH
END
```

Iam getting an exeception like incorrect syntax near `THROW` can some tell where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName
@Id INT,
@user_id INT
AS
 BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [transName]
    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE 
        FROM    table1
        WHERE   UserId= @user_id 

        UPDATE  table2
        SET     DATE_MODIFIED = GETDATE()
        WHERE   ID= @Id

        COMMIT TRANSACTION [transName]

    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();

SELECT  CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS NVARCHAR(1000));

THROW;
END CATCH
END
```